# using font awesome with smartmenus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am trying to create a responsive dropdown menu with submenus. Since the Bootstrap doesn't support them anymore, I am trying the one here: http://www.smartmenus.org/ The problem I have is that I am unable to use Font Awesome with it. My question on their forum remains unanswered. Was anyone able to use font awesome with smartmenu? 
When including:

```
<li> <a <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>&nbsp;   Database </a>
```

into their demo, I have the icon corrupted.

Jan

Comment: Are you loading font awesome?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried it in this way by also closing the first a tag?

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>&nbsp; Database </a></li>
```

and also if your not including the font awesome try including it in your head tags like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion works, but only with with smart menus basic version, not with  http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar-static-top.html - which is the version I would prefer

Comment: I am glad the first version worked for you, would be even happier if you marked as answered and/or positive on my question :p

Comment: sure, thanks again. I just didn't know where and what to click.